# Tkinter, How do i save the entry/dropdown selection to a str variable in my script

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have searched for answers to this question and always get sent back to printing the selection with print(var.get()).

**I don't want to print** the selection, but to **store it in a variable** that I can then use in my code.

For more context, I'm making a simple gui to **filter data frames**. There are a bunch of dropdown menus from which the user selects **specific features**. I then want to get all of those features to **filter down my data frame to a single entry**.
The code snippet below shows what I'm trying, but I don't know how to get the data frame that the function filter_df returns (the data frame df is defined before).

I'd also need to use the value of each previous dropdown menu to **remove all the impossible feature values (as in, no entry has both the previous value and the one I select after)**.

Is any of this possible, or are there elements I'm going to have to find a way around ?

*I thank any and all answers in advance, this website is what makes the (or at least my) coding world go round.*

```
app = tk.Tk()

app.geometry('100x200')

detail_app_str = tk.StringVar(app)
detail_app_str.set('Select Scope')
detail_dropedown = tk.OptionMenu(app, detail_app_str, *feature_values)
detail_dropedown.config(width=90, font=('Helvetica', 12))
detail_dropedown.pack(side="top")

def filter_df(*args):
    filtered_df = df[(df['A'] == int(detail_app_str.get()))]
    return filtered_df
detail_app_str.trace_add("write", filter_df)
```

Comment: If you want to store the information in a variable its as simple as `my_var = var.get()`.  What have you tried?

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: @Rory I tried that, but it returns the String that serves as the dropdown title but not the string I select in the dropdown menu

Comment: You appear to have a typo in `int(Detail_app_str.get()))` where `Detail` is capitalized. Should it be `int(detail_app_str.get()))`?

Comment: @jRiggles, I just renamed the variables in the code snippit to post it here for clarity hence the typo, but that's not it, my code doesn't have it.